# Get a photo associated with the current user

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to return a user a photo from Firebase node to the respected authenticated user. I have the Firebase set up so that when you register it, it creates a child record for the user, stores the UID there and also stores the image URL. As well as storing the image in Firebase storage.

I can get back the users email address they registered with but I cannot get the information related to the authenticated user in Firebase.

I want to return the users photo as a profile image qhen they login, currently just the email returns. I am using the below code:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        user?.let {
            for (profile in it.providerData) {
                // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
                val providerId = profile.providerId

                // UID specific to the provider
                val uid = profile.uid

                // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                val name = profile.displayName
                val email = profile.email
                val photoUrl = profile.photoUrl

                Log.d("photo", "${profile.photoUrl} + ${profile.uid}")
```

Rules for firebase:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "users":
        {
            "$userId":
            {
                ".read": "auth.uid === $userId",
                ".write": "auth.uid === $userId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I print out to console to see what is returning and each time i get null for photoUrl

Comment: Please add your database strucutre and please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @alexMamo I have updated the post with the databae rules. My structure is a user nodes, with uid, username, and profileimageurl

Comment: @AlexMamo see the above msg